# Using XSLT to convert tags in XML into another format is not working properly

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to write a stylesheet capable of converting a XML into another XML with the desired format.

The original XML has the following code:

```
    <Header>
        <owner>Person</owner>
        <version>1</version>
        <type>C</type>
        <publishTime>2018-07-11T10:27:15.917+01:00</publishTime>
        <ns2:Infos>
            <ns2:Info>
                <key>Context</key>
                <value>23276</value>
            </ns2:Info>
        </ns2:Infos>
    </Header>
    <payload id="APOL3001">
        <concept id="IMPOST" value="27,33"/>
        <concept id="RISCOS">
            <concept id="1">
                <concept id="CODRIS" value="101"/>
                <concept id="DESRIS" value="stuff"/>
                <concept id="VALFRQ" value="0"/>
                <concept id="INDFRQ" value="0"/>
                <concept id="DIAFRQ" value="000"/>
                <concept id="CAPTAL" value="117.755,82"/>
                <concept id="ZFMIN" value="000000000"/>
                <concept id="CAPFRQ" value="0%"/>
            </concept>
        </concept>
    </payload>
</iDocMessage>
```

The desired output is to take the ids and values and make those the tags and the values of those tags, for which I have written the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="concept">
    <xsl:element name="{@id}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="payload">
      <xsl:element name="{@id}">
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that it's outputting the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<iDocMessage xmlns:ns2="http://imessage.com/ws/core">
  <Header>
    <owner>Person</owner>
    <version>1</version>
    <type>C</type>
    <publishTime>2018-07-11T10:27:15.917+01:00</publishTime>
    <ns2:Infos>
      <ns2:Info>
        <key>Context</key>
        <value>23276</value>
      </ns2:Info>
    </ns2:Infos>
  </Header>
  <APOL3001></APOL3001>
</iDocMessage>
```

As you can see it's ignoring the indentation and not even showing the tags when it's doing the conversion of the Concept tags. Even if I delete the payload conversion it shows only the first 2 concept tags as converted. What am I missing?

Also, how can I make it so it adds a `<root> and <DOC>` tags at the start and end of the XML?

You can see the elements I have shown in action in the following link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxc/2

Edit:

The desired output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<iDocMessage xmlns:ns2="http://imessage.com/ws/core">
  <Header>
    <owner>Person</owner>
    <version>1</version>
    <type>C</type>
    <publishTime>2018-07-11T10:27:15.917+01:00</publishTime>
    <ns2:Infos>
      <ns2:Info>
        <key>Context</key>
        <value>23276</value>
      </ns2:Info>
    </ns2:Infos>
  </Header>
  <APOL3001></APOL3001>
    <IMPOST>27,33</IMPOST>
    <RISCOS>
      <1>
        <CODRIS>101</CODRIS>
        <DESRIS>stuff</DESRIS>
        ...
      </1>
    </RISCOS>
  </APOL3001>
</iDocMessage>
```

Comment: Well, `payload` and `concept` are nested so to process them all you need some `apply-templates` in their respective templates but it is not clear which output you want for those elements that contain other elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The desired output is for the nested elements inside APOL3001 to appear and have the same appearance as the other tags... with id and value transformed into `<id> value </id>`

Comment: @Konetchi, please edit your original post and add desired output as XML.

Comment: Your current description and code makes sense to convert leaf elements `<concept id="CODRIS" value="101"/>` into `<CODRIS>101</CODRIS>` but you have not explained what you want as output for elements having an `id` attribute but then nested child elements. And you will need to keep processing up with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to reach all levels in the tree.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the desired output. @MartinHonnen what do you mean by applying it to every level? I'm still very new to XSLT... do you have an example?

Comment: With a numeric ID the schema to map ID values to element names will fail as `<1>` is not allowed in XML. As for using `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, well, see the answer by now posted.

Comment: That's true, provided error "Name cannot begin with the '1' character", there could be a way to match this value and update the element name when it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly said by Martin, it could be formatted like below to get the expected output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="concept">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string(number(@id)) != 'NaN'">
            <xsl:element name="{concat('Number_',@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{@id}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="payload">
    <xsl:element name="{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyne2

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This stylesheet seems to ignore the original identation. Is there any way to make it indent the same way?

Comment: By checking if the attribute is numeric value, we can change it accordingly. Edited the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: By removing '<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>', it will preserve original indentation.

Comment: Thanks. You can close the question by accepting answer if you got your expected output.